# how to parse parameters without leading hyphen with Getopt

Tags: java, c, command-line-arguments, getopt

I am trying to parse command line arguments using `Getopt`.
However, some of my arguments are from the form `host myhost server myserver` where `host` and `server` are constants and `myhost` and `myserver` are changing arguments.

Can I parse options like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to preprocess the `argv` array (preferably copying it to a new location rather than trying to modify it in-place) to conform to the expected form, then use `getopt`. However, that's probably a lot more work that it's worth and might still have corner cases that break. `getopt` is intended only for use with utilities whose options conform to the POSIX guidelines. I would just write your own argument-processing code; actually that's my preference even when `getopt` would work because I usually prefer data-driven (e.g. an array of structs describing the possible options/arguments, their types, and how they should be stored) command line processing to code-driven (`switch` statement with explicit code for each option).